# Why aren't the chosen columns disabled?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to disable some columns so the users can't change the values. And then I want to save my input and write it to xlsx.

https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/

I have tried to use the examples as in link.

```
#Import data
iris


render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable)
}

#Dashboard
header = dashboardHeader()
sidebar = dashboardSidebar()
body = dashboardBody(fluidRow(
  DTOutput("test")
  )

)

ui = dashboardPage(skin = "yellow", header, sidebar, body)

server = function(input, output, session) {

     output$test = render_dt(iris, list(target = "row", disable = list (columns = c(2, 3, 4))))

     observeEvent(input$test_cell_edit, {
       iris <<- editData(iris, input$test_cell_edit, 'test')
     })
     observeEvent(session$isClosed()==T,{
      isolate(write.xlsx(iris, file = "test.xlsx"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I was expecting columns number 2, 3 and 4 would be locked and I could edit other columns. But all columns are editable.

Comment: can you please make your example reproduceable? I can spot multiple mistakes on the fly, but I am not sure if everything would work the way I think

Comment: @DSGym; Made some edits; should be reproduceable now.

Comment: no, the dashboardpage only contains placeholders so far :-(. `object 'header' not found`

Comment: Edited again :)

Comment: Hi. I tested it and the columns are locked as they should be. Please check that you have the latest version of DT. See changes in version 0.6 https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/NEWS.md.

Comment: Hi @EliBerkow packageVersion("DT") tells me I have got DT version 0.7. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which browser are you using? For me, on Chrome it greys out and on Internet Explorer it appears the same but doesn't allow editing.

Comment: Does the example in the link work for you?

Comment: No it doesn't work either. I tried it in Rstudio and in Shiny App.